# What is the correct way to call [super layoutSubviews]?

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, sdk

I just saw in the Facebook SDK for iOS that they call `[super layoutSubviews];` at the end and not at the beginning of the `layoutSubviews` method.

As far as I know, we should always do it as the first line.
Can implementing it a different way cause any unexpected UI behavior?

```
- (void)layoutSubviews
{
  CGSize size = self.bounds.size;
  CGSize longTitleSize = [self sizeThatFits:size title:[self _longLogInTitle]];
  NSString *title = (longTitleSize.width <= size.width ?
                     [self _longLogInTitle] :
                     [self _shortLogInTitle]);
  if (![title isEqualToString:[self titleForState:UIControlStateNormal]]) {
    [self setTitle:title forState:UIControlStateNormal];
  }

  [super layoutSubviews];
}
```

Comment: "As far as I know we should always do it as the first line" How do you "know" that?

Comment: @matt, I believe this is the convention the iOS Developers Community uses as the super-class may have some default/general setup that may affect our custom layout not to be applied(if we do it at the end of the method). Similarly to calling super in constructors/initializers as the first line.

Comment: "the super-class may have some default/general setup that may affect our custom layout not to be applied(if we do it at the end of the method)." Yes, that's absolutely true. But that's not the same as "should always".

Answer (score 9):

According to the [UIView Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/layoutSubviews),

> The default implementation of this method does nothing on iOS 5.1 and earlier. Otherwise, the default implementation uses any constraints you have set to determine the size and position of any subviews.

Thus, that the Facebook SDK example app calls `[super layoutSubviews]` at the end of their implementation could be an artifact of the app being initially built for an iOS version prior to iOS 5.1.

For more recent versions of iOS, you should call `[super layoutSubviews]` at the beginning of your implementation. Otherwise, the superclass will rearrange your subviews after you do the custom layout, effectively ignoring your implementation of `layoutSubviews()`.

Answer (score 5):

look into the code, before [super layoutSubviews], it is not about the frame. so put it at the end may work well too.
I guess the coder must want to check the title and modify the title based on some rules, he thinks everytime the layoutSubviews being called is a right opportunity to do that, so he put the code here.

Answer (score 3):

You always have to call `[super layoutSubviews]` last, if the intrinsic content size of a view will be changed. If you change the title of the button, the intrinsic content size of the `UIButton` will be changed, therefore the last call.

The first call to `[super layoutSubviews]` is always required because iOS updates the layout based on the constraints.
However, the technical most correct way of implementing your sample should be:

```
- (void)layoutSubviews
{
 [super layoutSubviews];
  CGSize size = self.bounds.size;
  CGSize longTitleSize = [self sizeThatFits:size title:[self _longLogInTitle]];
  NSString *title = (longTitleSize.width <= size.width ?
                     [self _longLogInTitle] :
                     [self _shortLogInTitle]);
  if (![title isEqualToString:[self titleForState:UIControlStateNormal]]) {
    [self setTitle:title forState:UIControlStateNormal];
  }

  [super layoutSubviews];
}
```

Comment: Just curious: is your claim about intrinsic content size backed up in the documentation anywhere?

Comment: Unfortunately not,  but If you think about it: The intrinsic content size can only be updated with setNeedsLayout, which directly calls layoutSubviews. If you change the intrinsic content size (change button title) in layoutSubviews the container (Button) cannot apply these changes properly if [super layoutSubviews] will not be called afterwards.

Comment: @ndmeiri When running against iOS7, I've seen runtime errors if I only call [super layoutSubviews] first: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Auto Layout still required after executing -layoutSubviews. {VIEW}'s implementation of -layoutSubviews needs to call super.'

Answer (score -1):

I recommend ["Programming iOS" Matt Neuberg.](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/programming-ios-14/9781492092162/) It's my *source of truth* when I have problems like this described here.

Here is the quote that describes the rule:

> (...) you might override `layoutSubviews` when you’re using autolayout, in order to tweak the outcome. A typical structure is: first you call `super`, causing all the subviews to adopt their new frames; then you examine those frames; if you don’t like the outcome, you can change things; and finally you call `super` *again*, to get a new layout outcome.

(page 80)