# understanding layoutSubviews different behaviors

Tags: swift, autolayout, uistackview, cornerradius, layoutsubviews

I have two group of buttons.

They should have rounded rects for different screen sizes.

so I wrote:

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    submitButton.layer.cornerRadius = updateButton.bounds.size.height / 2
    cancelButton.layer.cornerRadius = cancelButton.bounds.size.height / 2
}
```

This works as the imageBelow

[image]

However when I add `super.layoutSubviews()` before or after, it will just give non-rounded rects like this:

[image]

<sub>FYI these 2 buttons are inside a horizontal `stackView`.</sub>

Then I have another screen where if I don't add `super.layoutSubviews()` then the button won't have rounded rects.

[image]

<sub>FYI This button isn't inside a `stackView` It has top, bottom and centerX constraints.</sub>

**So basically at one view using `super.layoutSubviews()` will help you to create rounded rects, at another it would obstruct it!!**

The setting of these buttons is:

```
btn.clipsToBounds = true
btn.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
btn.layer.borderColor = Constants.Color.CoolBlue.color().cgColor
btn.contentEdgeInsets.top = 15
btn.contentEdgeInsets.bottom = 10
btn.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
```

Is this because of stackViews or something else? Why is behaving like this?

I've already read [What is the correct way to call [super layoutSubviews]?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31347772/what-is-the-correct-way-to-call-super-layoutsubviews) and tried to write `super.layoutSubviews()` both before and after my code, but that didn't help.

Comment: Its an interesting question. I don't have the answer but what about calling: `submitButton.layer.cornerRadius = updateButton.bounds.size.height / 2` in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`? There is no need to call `super` in this case.

Comment: This is a UIView, not UIViewController. `layoutSubviews` is the UIView equivalent of UIViewController's `viewDidLayoutSubviews`. I'm almost certain for both you have to call `super.` otherwise things may go wrong.

Comment: Do not set corner rounding in `layoutSubiews`. It is not layout of subviews.

Comment: @matt Hah! Seeing your comment on the linked question I was hoping you'd join... I'm following the approach mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31961794/5175709) so I could give correct rounded rects for different screen sizes. What alternative do I have then?

Comment: I would make a UIButton subclass that knows how to round its _own_ corners depending on its size

Comment: @matt OK, I'll do that then. Can you explain why it's behaving different?

Comment: if you set btn.clipsToBounds = true then you can just set btn.layer.cornerRadius / borderWidth / borderColor to whatever you are interested in. there's no need to call layoutSubviews. 

If you are interested in force a refresh of your layout you should use btn.layoutIfNeeded which has an internal call to layoutSubviews method.